# Google sheets switches cell range?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This one is odd, I think. I am creating arrays in g-sheets where I want the range to be A:A300. I enter A:A300 into the formula, but when I hit enter and then check the formula again it changes it to be A300:A, which of course doesn't work. I can enter A1:A300 and it works fine, but why would it swap the starting/ending parameters?

Answer (score 1):

If you leave an open-ended range (meaning like A1:A,A1:1, not using one of the variables) it will go to the end of that column or row, and not the other way round. Then your range A:A300 actually goes from A300 to A1000 or whichever row is your last one. Then, the order Sheets stablish to your range is logically correct